# NSDictionary and plist not reading in values (my while loops might be the issue)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LevelsData</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>StoneOne</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Column</key>
                <integer>2</integer>
                <key>Row</key>
                <integer>2</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>StoneTwo</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Column</key>
                <integer>3</integer>
                <key>Row</key>
                <integer>4</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>Target</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Column</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>Row</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>Horizontal1</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Column</key>
                <integer>2</integer>
                <key>Row</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>Horizontal2</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Column</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>Row</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>Horizontal3</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Column</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>Row</key>
                <integer>3</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>GhostHorizontal1</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Column</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>Row</key>
                <integer>3</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>GhostHorizontal2</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Column</key>
                <integer>4</integer>
                <key>Row</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>Vertical1</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Column</key>
                <integer>3</integer>
                <key>Row</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>Vertical2</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Column</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>Row</key>
                <integer>2</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>Vertical3</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Column</key>
                <integer>3</integer>
                <key>Row</key>
                <integer>4</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

In my my Model.m file I have:

```
    -(void)setToVerticalState {
        int i = 1;
        while (_data[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertical%i", i]] != nil) {
            NSDictionary* vertical = _data[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertical%i", i]];
            // _column and _row are NSNumber instance variables
            _column = vertical[@"Column"];
            _row = vertical[@"Row"];
            NSInteger column = [_column intValue];
            NSInteger row = [_row intValue];
            [super setVBarCellState:VerticalState forVBarCol:column andVBarRow:row];
            i++;
        }   

        int j = 1;
        while (_data[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"GhostVertical%i", j]] != nil) {
            NSDictionary* ghostV = _data[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"GhostVertical%i", j]];
            _column = ghostV[@"Column"];
            _row = ghostV[@"Row"];
            NSInteger column = [_column intValue];
            NSInteger row = [_row intValue];
            [super setVBarCellState:GhostHorizontalState forVBarCol:column andVBarRow:row];
            j++;
        }
    }

    - (instancetype)initWithLevelIndex:(NSUInteger)levelsIndex {
       self = [super init];
       if (self) {
           NSString* filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                          pathForResource:@"Levels" ofType:@"plist"];
           NSDictionary *levels = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
           NSArray *levelsArray = levels[@"LevelsData"];
           _data = levelsArray[levelsIndex];
          [_verticalB setToInitialStateVertical];
       }
       return self;
    }  

    - (Model*)verticalB {
        // @property (nonatomic) Model* verticalB;
        return _verticalB;
    }
```

And in my ViewController.m file:

```
    -(void)setUp {
        Model* vBoard = [[Model alloc] init];
        _verticalBoard = vBoard.verticalB;
        // _verticalBoard is my Model* instance variable for ViewController.m
    }
```

So what's going on in a nutshell:

1. Via my AppDelegate.m, initWithLevelIndex: is called, loading the plist.
2. In that method, setToVerticalState method is called, loading the states with their respective information.
3. Then, in ViewController.m, I get a reference to the _verticalB states.
4. WHAT YOU DON'T SEE: After I get that reference, I initialize the View setup with the reference information (basically, tell the initializer the Column and Row values for each VerticalState, so that their images can be placed appropriately on the screen.

I am unable to see any image, and I feel that the while loops are the problem. I don't even know if they are executing at all, which means the column/row information isn't being stored anywhere.  Thanks for bearing with me here.

Comment: add some breakpoints and logs to see what it and isn't called

Comment: All my instance variables stored in 'verticalB' (in the setUp method) are nil.  And, the way I figured, they should be set to something by that point.  Any thoughts?  Does the code I wrote make sense, validity wise?

Comment: _data (the NSDictionary) is nil too

Comment: if `_data` is nil nothing else matters until you work out why...

Comment: If you are using ARC, the `Model` instance you create in your `ViewController`'s `setUp` method will be created and immediately deallocated. Also, the `Model` you're creating (even if for a very brief moment) is not the same instance as the one in your `AppDelegate`, which is where you appear to be properly calling `initWithLevelIndex:` which is what does all the setup work.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying. Just to let you know, that _verticalB receiver that the setUpVerticalState message gets passed to is a Model* property that I also have written out in Model.m in order for its information to be accessed.  So, going back to setUp method, I should still be accessing the same information or no?

Comment: Either way, what you said about the Model I'm creating not being the same instance as the one in AppDelegate...how should I handle that problem?

Comment: At one point, when I had a breakpoint at _data = levelsArray[levelsIndex], _data actually had the 18 key-value pairs.  But every other time it has the value nil